# Efficient searching through matrices

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, scipy

```
Y1=scipy.zeros((l,l))
y_test=scipy.zeros((l,l))

for i in range(0,l):
    for j in range(0,l):

        if y_score[i][j]>=0.1:
            Y1[i][j]=1


for i in range(0,l):
    for j in range(0,l):
        if (Y1[i][j]==1) and (v[i][j]==1):
            y_test[i][j]=1
```

I am working with large large datasets and I have to search through the matrix.The time is O(n^2) in the worst case.Is there a better and faster method to do the above tasks using numpy and scipy?

The inputs are y_score which is a 100,000X100,000 numpy array with values between 0 and 1.
v is a sparse scipy matrix with similar dimensions.

Comment: What exactly are the inputs? Are those arrays? What's `sc`?

Comment: @Divakar I edited the question.Thanks

Comment: What about `y_score`?

Comment: Also, shouldn't that be : `(Y1[i][j]==1) and (v[i,j]==1):`?

Comment: You might want to edit the question as it states : `v is a sparse scipy matrix`.

Comment: `v` is a sparse matrix can make a big difference.  Just how sparse is (number of nonzero items compared to the overall dimension)?  Matrix multiplication is a sparse matrix strong point.  Indexing and iteration it's weakness.

Comment: Any feedback on posted solutions?

Answer (score 0):

You can simply create masks corresponding to the comparisons and then convert them to float (if you need them in that dtype) for the desired outputs -

```
mask = y_score >= 0.1
Y1 = mask.astype(float)
y_test = (mask & (v==1)).astype(float)
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend reading Numpy's indexing documentation:
https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.indexing.html

Numpy is good at bulk operations.

Your example could simply be translated to:

```
import scipy

l = 10
Y1 = scipy.zeros((l, l))
y_test = scipy.zeros((l, l))
y_score = scipy.random.rand(l, l)
v = scipy.random.randint(0, 2, (l, l))

Y1[y_score >= 0.1] = 1
y_test[(Y1 == 1) & (v == 1)]
```

Comment: but the problem is my input array has dimensions 100,000X100,000.

Comment: Okay, you could work on slices if it doesn't fit into memory. But perhaps @Divakar 's answer works better for your use case?